# 同じネットワークにつながっている端末のそれぞれIPアドレスを調べるには

Tags: macos, bash

同じネットワークにつながっているそれぞれIPアドレスを調べるにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

条件

```
機器１ AB:CD:EF:12:34:01
機器２ AB:CD:EF:12:34:02 
機器３ AB:CD:EF:12:34:03
機器４ MACアドレス不明
```

全て、同一のローカルネットワークに接続しています。

試している案は下記の通りです。

同じNW上の全てのIPに対してpingをしたうえで、ARPテーブルを取得し、
MACアドレスと照合する。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
for ((i = 100 ; i <= 254 ; i++)); do ping -c 1 -t 1 10.242.15.${i}; done
arp -a
???
???
```

結果は下記のように取得できましたが、時間がかかりすぎます。
もう少し効率的な方法があればご教示ください。

```
? (10.242.16.42) at AB:CD:EF:12:34:01 on en5 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.242.16.50) at AB:CD:EF:12:34:04 on en5 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.242.16.146) at AB:CD:EF:12:34:03 on en5 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.242.18.78) at AB:CD:EF:12:34:02 on en5 ifscope [ethernet]
```

また、機器ごとのMACアドレスから、それぞれの機器のIPアドレスを変数で呼べるようにしたいのですが、どうするのがよいでしょうか。
（機器１のIPアドレスを、シェル変数 EQ_IPADDR1とした場合）

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arp-scan`というツールを入手し試してみてください。

```
$ arp-scan --interface=eth0 192.168.0.0/24
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.4 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.0.1     00:c0:9f:09:b8:db       QUANTA COMPUTER, INC.
192.168.0.3     00:02:b3:bb:66:98       Intel Corporation
192.168.0.5     00:02:a5:90:c3:e6       Compaq Computer Corporation
192.168.0.6     00:c0:9f:0b:91:d1       QUANTA COMPUTER, INC.
192.168.0.12    00:02:b3:46:0d:4c       Intel Corporation
192.168.0.13    00:02:a5:de:c2:17       Compaq Computer Corporation
192.168.0.87    00:0b:db:b2:fa:60       Dell ESG PCBA Test
192.168.0.90    00:02:b3:06:d7:9b       Intel Corporation
192.168.0.105   00:13:72:09:ad:76       Dell Inc.
192.168.0.153   00:10:db:26:4d:52       Juniper Networks, Inc.
192.168.0.191   00:01:e6:57:8b:68       Hewlett-Packard Company
192.168.0.251   00:04:27:6a:5d:a1       Cisco Systems, Inc.
192.168.0.196   00:30:c1:5e:58:7d       HEWLETT-PACKARD
13 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan: 256 hosts scanned in 3.386 seconds (75.61 hosts/sec).  13
responded
```

Answer (score 1):

ブロードキャストアドレス宛に ping を打つという手があります。ただし、ブロードキャスト宛の ping に応答しない端末もあります。また、通常は root 権限が必要です。Linux の `ping` では `-b` オプションが必要なことが多いです。

```
# ping -b 10.242.15.255
```

`ping` をバックグラウンドでガンガン起動して、すべての `ping` が終了するのを待ってから `arp -a` で確認するという手も考えられます。

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i = 100 ; i <= 254 ; i++)); do ping -c 1 -t 1 10.242.15.${i} & done
wait
arp -a
```

シェル変数 `EQ_IPADDR?` にセットしたいなら次のような感じでしょうか。
MAC アドレスの最後の数だけで変数名を決めたいなら `sed` のスクリプトを適宜調整してください。

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i = 100 ; i <= 254 ; i++)); do
  ping -c 1 -t 1 10.242.15.${i} >/dev/null 2>&1 &
done
wait

while read n ip; do
  eval "EQ_IPADDR$n"='"$ip"'
done < <(arp -an |sed -n 's/://g;s/^.*(\(.*\)) at \([0-9a-f]*\).*/\2 \1/p')
set |grep EQ_IPADDR
```

Comment: fpingというツールは並列にpingで走査してくれるので、ご回答の「pingをバックグラウンド」部分はもっとお手軽になります。

Answer (score 0):

アプリケーションを自由に導入できるのであれば、他の回答にあるようなツールを始め同種のツールが多数あるのでそちらを使ってください。

ツールを導入せずに実現しなければならないのであれば、少々乱暴ですが

```
for ((i = 100 ; i <= 254 ; i++)); do ping -c 1 -t 1 10.242.15.${i} &; done
```

でpingをバックグラウンドで実行するか、シェルスクリプトで完結しなくて良いなら、pingの代わりにこんなperlスクリプトでパケットを送りつけるのが手っ取り早いでしょうか。

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Socket;

my $port = 7000;
socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
foreach my $i( 1 .. 254)
{
    my $addr = inet_aton("172.16.1.$i");
    my $sock_addr = pack_sockaddr_in($port, $addr); 
    send(SOCKET, "0", 0, $sock_addr);
}
```

2番目の質問ですが、`EQ_IPADDRn`の`n`が何に対応するのかよく分かりません。シェルスクリプトでちょっとでも複雑なことをやろうとするととたんに黒魔術的なことになるので、シェルスクリプトを極めたいのでもないかぎり、他の言語を使われる事をお勧めします。perlならたいていの環境には標準で入ってるでしょう。